# Can some one help me understand a sentence in this video?

Tags: spoken-english, indian-english, accent

This wonderful YouTuber has helped me a great deal learning algorithms but the subtitles don't seem to make sense to me, here the subs merged with what I hear:

> "... I have told you in one video in asymptotic notation, that cases are no way related to notation. So notations are for the functions cases are the **just/gist(?)** of type of analysis done on an algorithm."

[Here](https://youtu.be/lj3E24nnPjI?list=PLDN4rrl48XKpZkf03iYFl-O29szjTrs_O&t=533) the link right at the position of the video.

Comment: The speaker has a strong Indian accent, so it's not easy to tell (especially as I don't understand the subject), but I think he says 'cases are just a type of analysis done on an algorithm'.

Comment: If you wanted to learn *English*, this guy wouldn't be a good source (but presumably that's not your intention here!). I find him almost impossible to understand myself, and we Brits are usually quite good at "tuning" our ear to different accents, on account of always having had so many native accents *and* now huge numbers of non-native Anglophones. But it's not just a difficult accent - he doesn't seem to be very good at choosing the right words either. I think he *intends* to say *cases are just a type of analysis* (he shouldn't say ***the***) but exactly what that means isn't clear to me.

Comment: I think he says _another/one video on asymptotic notation_ at the beginning so he started saying one word an then corrected himself. As you probably know the whiteboard has examples of asymptotic notation. The remainder of it is a bit of a mystery to me and I am not unused to hearing Indian English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELL isn't a video transcription service. Particularly when the source is such poor quality English (with absolutely appalling enunciation).

Comment: @FumbleFingers First of all given the sheer amount of people speaking Indian-English alone I find it desirable to learn understanding it. Secondly given I will be looking for jobs in IT it is strongly advised to learn to understand ALL accents. Many bosses are from India, Hongkong, Pakistan. If you are unable to understand the interviewer you will not go to the next round in the interviews. It is a common recommendation for IT interview preparation. It is also good to leave behind the colonialist additude... BTW UK/NZ and Aussie English are just as hard for me to understand - again --> netflix

Comment: The guy in this particular clip is *not* a good example of Indian English. It's not just that terrible accent - he clearly isn't very good at choosing the right words. And I'm more familiar than most with spoken Indian English, because most of my closest neighbours are Indian or Pakistani. Plus the BBC in particular are very hot on promoting both "foreign" *and* local native British accents.

Comment: Nobody is being 'colonialist', just telling you that we find this particular speaker's diction very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FumbleFingers has it right. "Cases are just for analysis". That said, I know the material he is teaching. I think his accent and delivery get in the way of learning this material. I  question his pedagogy too. I am sure there are better places to read about big-O worst and average case algorithm analysis. There are probably better videos too.

Comment: [Abdul Bari](https://www.udemy.com/user/mohammed-abdul-bari-2/) is recommended by many professors, including mine particularly because of being extremely concise. He is highly regarded in the field and some jobs require you to do his courses on Udemy. I find it weird and not that you have to lash out especially as it is just not nice. Thanks how ever for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't intend to be nasty - just to say that from my experience I thought there might be other places to learn. People learn in different ways.

Comment: Heh. I had a prof who kept talking about "ee kyoov ya lent" things.  Since he kept writing the correct symbol for "equivalent" I eventually started to understand.  Another prof apologized for his accent by explaining that his students always got upset when he talked about "tragic torries" while discussing the paths particles take.